# Backbone templates getting started: How to go from append() to using a template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-templates, mustache, icanhaz.js

This is a very basic question on how to get started using templates. This is literally my first time using backbone so any additional pointers on how to improve my code are appreciated:

example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/H93Ej/12/

for the following snippet:

```
    addFurnitureLi: function (model) {
        // Add a new piece of furniture to the DOM list
        $("#furniture-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");
    }
```

I would like to go from using `append()` to using a template like this:

```
<script id="furnitureTemplate" type="text/html">

    <li>{{ name }}</li>

</script>
```

But I'm lost as to how to integrate the above script template into the `addFurnitureLi` function. Also, I feel as though essentially the `addFurnitureLi` function is "rendering" HTML on the page, so I have another question-- what is the difference between that function and an "official" `render` function?

Thank you for educating me!

Full app code is listed below:

```
(function($) {

    Furniture = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            "name" : null,
            "quantity" : 1
        }
    });

    Furnitures = Backbone.Collection.extend({       
        initialize: function (models, options) {
            this.bind("add", options.view.addFurnitureLi);
            //Listen for new additions to the collection and call a view function if so
        }
    });

    FurnitureView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function () {
            this.furnitures = new Furnitures( null, { view: this });
        },
        events: {
            "click .furniture-add":  "addFurnitureModel",
        },
        addFurnitureModel: function (ev) {
            // Add a piece of furniture to the model
            var furnitureName = $(ev.currentTarget).data('name'),
                furnitureModel = new Furniture({ name: furnitureName });

            this.furnitures.add( furnitureModel);   
        },
        addFurnitureLi: function (model) {
            // Add a new piece of furniture to the DOM list
            $("#furniture-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");
        }
    });


    var furnitureView = new FurnitureView;

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Boom shakah-lakah.

given that the ID of your template script is `furnitureTemplate`:

```
<script id="furnitureTemplate" type="text/html">

    <li>{{ name }}</li>

</script>
```

This works fine:

```
 addFurnitureLi: function (model) {
        // Add a new piece of furniture to the DOM list
        $('#furniture-list').append( ich.furnitureTemplate( model.toJSON() ) );
 }
```